# how to use insert values into database using php

Tags: php

```
$value2=$_POST['c_name'];
$value3=$_POST['c_vehicle_number'];
$value4=$_POST['c_phone'];
$value5=$_POST['c_email'];
```

these are the values stored in 1.php.

i want insert those values in 2.php.as below,

```
$sql="insert into customer_details(c_id,c_name,c_vehicle_number,c_phone,c_email) values ('','$value2','$value3','$value4','$value5')";
```

=====================================================
am using require('1.php');
which does not insert the values into the database.
what would be the soluton.?

Comment: How you can use those variables on another page?

Comment: u need to define that varibles globally..better u use FORM in 1.php n it will post ur all data to another page..http://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Comment: am using require('1.php');which is not working,what would be the other way?

Comment: @Ashish variables globally? instead he should shift the code from 1 to 2.php and than use the post method and action set on form to to form 2.php

Comment: @Mr.Alien i would have written the code in 1.php itself instead of shifting the code,but,i need to use the values of the vars in an other file...

Comment: @Mr.Alien: sorry i gave him 2 options but forget to mention OR after 1st line...

Comment: global is working fine.thanks @Ashish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to enter a values into the DB one must have a connection to the Database.

1. Create a connection to the relevant database.
2. Perform our desired query.

**Example:**

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age)
VALUES
('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[age]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Explanation:

As you can see we first trying to retain a connection using `mysqli_connect` with the relevant `DATABASE-ADDRESS`, `USERNAME`, PASSWORD`and`DATABASE-NAME`

Than we're using `mysqli_query` to perform our query and we're passing it the connection we opened earlier + the query string we wish to perform.

More explanation could be found [HERE](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

**Important:** This example isn't `SQL-Injection` protected, and it's highly important to you, to be protected against it. Read about it [HERE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
$sql="INSERT into customer_details(c_id,c_name,c_vehicle_number,c_phone,c_email) VALUES ('".$_POST['value1']."','".$_POST['value1']."','".$_POST['value1']."','".$_POST['value1']."','".$_POST['value1']."')";
```

you worte :

```
('','$value2','$value3','$value4','$value5') you did mistake here
```

it can be write 
('".$value2."','".$value3."','".$value4."','".$value5."')